# Relational database show fields from different tables in view, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view, controller, relational-database

I have 4 tables, `customer`, `customer_site`, `site` and `connection`. `customer` and `site` have many `customer_sites` and a `site` has many `connections`. This has all been set up in my models. Now i'm trying to have a view for each customer, showing every connection linked to that customer. This is what i have in my view:

```
 <% @connection.each do |l| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= l.interface %></td>
      <td><%= l.device %></td>
      <td><%= l.speed %></td>
      <td><%= l.site.name %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

and this is my controller:

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @connection = Connection.all(where connection.site.customer_site.customer.id == params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @customer }
  end
end
```

obviously the `@connection` part isn't correct, i'm just not sure what I need to put in there to link  the records correctly...

Comment: Do your relationships use the `has_many :through` syntax? If so you may be able to simplify your search somewhat. Post your relations to help us make the most appropriate answer.

Comment: no, they only use `belongs_to` and `has_many` in each controller

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt mention in his comment, the easiest way is to use `has_many` associations with `:through` option.
You can read more about this in Rails [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_sites, foreign_key: :site_id
  has_many :connections
end

class CustomerSite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :customer
end
 
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_sites, foreign_key: :customer_id
  has_many :sites, through: :customer_sites
  has_many :connections, through: :sites
end
```

In controller:

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @connections = @customer.connections
  ...
end
```

Let me know, if it is not clear enough.

Comment: I've put this in, however I still don't know the correct syntax to get it to show in my view...

Comment: I've edited my answer. Also, please read a guide. There a lot more information about using associations.

Comment: I'm reading the guide as we speak, I've put that in my controller and still have `<% @connection.each do |l| %>` in my view yet i get the error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Use `@customer.connections` as in my answer.

Comment: I have. I then try to reference it in my view, with the above code, and get the error

Comment: had another go, now i get this error `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'sites.customer_site_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `connections`.* FROM `connections` INNER JOIN `sites` ON `connections`.`site_id` = `sites`.`id` INNER JOIN `customer_sites` ON `sites`.`customer_site_id` = `customer_sites`.`id` WHERE `customer_sites`.`customer_id` = 1`

Comment: You need to set `foreign_key` option on the `customer_site` association. I've edited my answer answer.